# Position of prompt >>> in stderr after SystemExit

Tags: python

I have a script _testing_.py containing just `raise SystemExit`. When I run it from cmdline using `py -i _testing_.py`, the traceback is printed and the the prompt >>> is printed. However when I run it as subprocess via Popen, i.e. `Popen("py -i _testing_.py", stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE).communicate()` the resulting stderr contains first the prompt >>> and then the traceback. Can you confirm this behaviour and explain it? I'm using Python 3.3.2 on Windows.

It seems thats it's dependent bahaviour. @jentyk's observation is that the order isn't exchanged in Python 2.7 on MacOS.

Comment: Can you drop in a full runable script showing the second behavior?

Comment: @agf: I almost have: `from subprocess import *; print(Popen("py -i _testing_.py", stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE).communicate()[1].decode())`. (The resulting stderr is bytes in the second element of the result of .communicate().)

Comment: Maybe it helps. I just tried under Python 2.7 on Mac OS X, and it works in both cases the same, I mean prompt after traceback. It can mean the behaviour you observed is Python version or operating system specific.

Comment: Wow! I just run it under Python 3.3 and indeed prompt is at the beginning! Weird...

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419787/where-does-pythons-interactive-prompt-output-to