# Where does Python's interactive prompt ">>>" output to?

Tags: python, python-interactive

I've run into a somewhat unusual situation. I'm trying to script the interactive console (for teaching/testing purposes), and I tried the following:

```
$ python > /dev/null
Python 2.7.3 (v2.7.3:70274d53c1dd, Apr  9 2012, 20:52:43) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print 3
>>>
```

`3` isn't printed, so clearly everything else was on `stderr`. So far so good. But then we redirect `stderr`:

```
$ python 2> /dev/null
>>> print 3
3
>>>
```

How can the prompt be printed in both cases?

EDIT: Redirecting both `stdout` and `stderr` causes absolutely nothing to be printed. So Python's clearly "choosing" one of `stdout` or `stderr`. Is that documented to happen? I couldn't figure out how this is actually done in the Python source code.

Comment: Huh, that's strange. Perhaps it checks `isatty`?

Comment: That'd be my guess, but I can't seem to figure out where Python actually does this. The weirdest thing is that `PyOS_StdioReadline`, the function which appears to be responsible for reading input, is hardcoded to print the prompt to `stderr`. If `stderr` were redirected to `stdout`, as the second example suggests, we should see the banner.

Comment: It might be easier to use a tool designed for teaching Python, like the [notebook feature of ipython](http://ipython.org/notebook.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like python checks whether `stdout` is a `tty`:

```
/* This is needed to handle the unlikely case that the
 * interpreter is in interactive mode *and* stdin/out are not
 * a tty.  This can happen, for example if python is run like
 * this: python -i < test1.py
 */
if (!isatty (fileno (sys_stdin)) || !isatty (fileno (sys_stdout)))
    rv = PyOS_StdioReadline (sys_stdin, sys_stdout, prompt);
else
    rv = (*PyOS_ReadlineFunctionPointer)(sys_stdin, sys_stdout,
                                         prompt);
```

Sourcecode from `Parser/myreadline.c` around line 194.

It's possible that the interpreter imports the `readline` module at startup, in which case `PyOS_ReadlineFunctionPointer` will be set to `call_readline`, which uses the `readline` library. In particular it calls [`rl_callback_handler_install`](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/readline/rlman_41.html). The documentation of this function doesn't state where the prompt is printed, but it's possible that it checks whether `stdout`/`stderr` are `tty`s.

Comment: Right above that, though, it seems to set `PyOS_ReadlineFunctionPointer` to `PyOS_StdioReadline` (except on VMS, which I'm definitely not on).

Comment: @nneonneo Yes, I'm I bit puzzled, but this is the only reference I can find that could somehow explain the behaviour you see. Do you have the readline library available? Because at the beginning of the file it mentions that it uses it when it is available.

Comment: @nneonneo It sets it only if it isn't `NULL`. If the interpreter imports the `readline` during startup then the `readline` module will set its function(see the init function at `Modules/readline.c`), and thus the `PyOS_Readline` will not use `PyOS_StdioReadline`.

Comment: Aha! I missed that detail. I guess this means that Python outputs the prompt to `stderr` only as a fallback...neat! Thanks for your answer.